# Equivalent definition for $C^k$ boundary

Tags: differential-geometry

In Evan's PDE, $C^k$ boundary is defined as

> Let $U\subseteq\mathbb {R}^n$ to be open and bounded. $\partial U$ is $C^k$ if for each point $x^0 \in \partial U$, there exists $r>0$ and a $C^k$ function $\gamma :\mathbb R^{n-1}\to \mathbb R$, upon renaming the coordinates,
> \begin{align} U\cap B(x^0,r)=\{x\in B(x^0,r)|x_n>\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\}  \end{align}

I am wondering if this kind of definition is too restrictive. Usually, the $C^k$ boundary is defines as that the boundary is locally a graph of a $C^k$ function. Evan's definition do imply the usual definition, since $x_n-\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})>0$ on the interior implies $x_n-\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\geq0$ on the closure and hence $x_n=\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$ on the boundary. However, I do not think these 2 definitions are equivalent, because Evan's definition is saying $x_n$ in the interior is always lager than $x_n$ in the boundary, which is clearly not always true. For example, the right-top part of a 2D ball, i.e $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 =1,x\geq 0, y\geq0 \}$, I think it is reasonable to say its boundary is $C^1$, but $x^n$ on the boundary is always lager than $x_n$ in the interior no matter which $x_n$ we choose.

If my reasoning is correct, I am wondering if

> Let $U\subseteq\mathbb {R}^n$ to be open and bounded. $\partial U$ is $C^k$ if for each point $x^0 \in \partial U$, there exists $r>0$ and a $C^k$ function $\gamma :\mathbb R^{n-1}\to \mathbb R$, upon renaming the coordinates,
> \begin{align} U\cap B(x^0,r)=\{x\in B(x^0,r)|x_n>\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\}  \end{align} or
> \begin{align} U\cap B(x^0,r)=\{x\in B(x^0,r)|x_n<\gamma(x_1,...,x_{n-1})\}  \end{align}

would be a equivalent definition of the usual definition of $C^k$ boundary

Comment: By choosing the coordinates correctly, Evan’s definition is equivalent to the usual definition.

Comment: @Nick How? I cannot see how to choose the coordinate to make it satisfying Evan's definition for my counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed definition is of course fine. But there is no issue with the definition in Evans—you misquoted it. It actually says "...—upon relabeling **and reorienting** the coordinate axes if necessary—...".

Comment: Oh, I got it, Thank you.  So, it basically allows both $>$ and $<$.

Comment: Do you have any idea of showing the equivalence? I thought about it yesterday, but I cannot show that. A hint is good enough.